# redundant question mark occurs when concatenate variable in bash with ps command

Tags: bash

Running bash file download.sh, `scp` shows "no such file" error. So I try to run the command `ps -efj | grep scp`, and console outputs:

```
love@192.168.1.105:/home/storage/static/test/res/house/res.zip_b077f446? ../logs/static/test/res/house/
```

A redundant question mark occurs in the file name and I think that causes the error info of "no such file". But `echo $SOURCE` output is `static/test/res/house/res_update.zip_61b25e4b`, no question mark.

download.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=love@192.168.1.105:/home/storage/
while read p; do
    PART_DIR=$(echo $p | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}{NF--; print}')
    DEST_DIR="../logs/${PART_DIR}" # directory for saving files 
    mkdir -p "${DEST_DIR}"
    SOURCE="${FILE}${p}" 
    echo $SOURCE # debug, output: static/test/res/house/res_update.zip_61b25e4b 
    scp -P 19061 $SOURCE "${DEST_DIR}/"
done <../logs/file.txt
```

file.txt

```
static/test/res/house/res.zip_b077f446
static/test/res/house/res_update.zip_61b25e4b
```

Comment: First glance guess, `\r\n` line ends or somesuch...

Comment: @DevSolar I tried `set list` in vim, and it shows: $ in every line.

Comment: In other words, I can't reproduce the problem ATM, and I'd much prefer if you could edit the script (and the description) to *just* reproduce the error, ideally without creating directories or requiring a specific setup of subdirectories / remote connections I do not have and do not want. Create a [mcve].

Comment: @DevSolar For `scp source dest`, I output the source value in two ways:1. `echo $SOURCE`. 2. `ps -efj | grep scp`. But for `ps` command, a redundant "?" occurs. So I try command `set list` in vim to check whether  `\r\n` exists in file `file.txt`, but it seems not(only `$` occurs at the end of every line in `file.txt`).

Comment: Run `file file.txt`. Does it say "ASCII text", or does it say "ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators"?

Comment: @DevSolar It says:"ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators". Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Use `dos2unix` to convert the line endings in `file.txt`. (Vim's `set list` is depending on the `listchars` set and can be deceiving.) Also, [`man dirname`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname) if you want to drop that `awk` bit in there.